# Extract unsigned short int from bytearray in Python

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I have a 4-bytes `bytearray` in Python, and I would like to extract two unsigned short int. bytes[0] and bytes[1] for the first number, and bytes[2] and bytes[3] for the second.

This is what I have for the moment:

```
bytes_payload = bytearray(string_payload)
print bytes_payload[0]
print bytes_payload[1]
print bytes_payload[2]
print bytes_payload[3]
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: check [`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `struct.unpack()` function to extract any variable types from byte array. In your case, you shall use

```
unpacked = struct.unpack("HH", bytes_payload)
print(unpacked[0])
print(unpacked[1])
```

First argument specifies, how to interpret bytes and you can combine specifiers any way yo want (if they match byte array size). Note that you may need to specify endianity too for correct data unpacking.